# Doctrine and LIKE query

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I have entity for Doctrine:

```
<?php
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="orders")
 */
class Orders {
    /** @Id @Column(name="OID",type="integer") @GeneratedValue */
    private $id;
    /** @Column(name="Product",type="string")*/
        private $product;
    /** @Column(name="RegCode",type="string")*/
        private $reg_code;
    /** @Column(name="OrderEmail",type="string")*/
    private $email;
}
```

I need make query like this:

```
select * from `orders` where `OrderEmail`='some@mail.com' and `Product` LIKE 'My Products%'
```

I try handle query without like:

```
$em->getRepository("Orders")->findByEmailAndProduct($uname,$product);
```

But it make error. Why?
Can I do this query without DQL? I want make this query use magic methods **findBy****

Comment: What error?
But there is no way to do this using `findBy*` because Doctrine don`t know what field you want to compare using `LIKE`

Answer (score 170, accepted):

This is not possible with the magic find methods. Try using the [query builder](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/query-builder.html):

```
$result = $em->getRepository("Orders")->createQueryBuilder('o')
   ->where('o.OrderEmail = :email')
   ->andWhere('o.Product LIKE :product')
   ->setParameter('email', 'some@mail.com')
   ->setParameter('product', 'My Products%')
   ->getQuery()
   ->getResult();
```

Comment: Thanks for example. Can I make group by use QueryBuilder?

Comment: I use doctrine with Zend Framework. Thaks for link on Symfony site. Maybe I find more information on it.

Comment: Yes you can use groupBy and a lot of other [helper methods](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/query-builder.html#helper-methods)

Answer (score 31):

You can use the `createQuery` method (direct in the controller) :

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT o FROM AcmeCodeBundle:Orders o WHERE o.OrderMail =  :ordermail and o.Product like :searchterm")
->setParameter('searchterm', '%'.$searchterm.'%')
->setParameter('ordermail', 'some@email.com');
```

You need to change AcmeCodeBundle to match your bundle name

Or even better - create a repository class for the entity and create a method in there - this will make it reusable

Comment: I know how make this query on DQL. Maybe you know how make it without DQL and why "findByEmailAndProduct" doesn't work.

Comment: @Evgeniy updated - you would need to test it as im not sure that the findby method uses like

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible with the magic methods, however you can achieve this using DQL ([Doctrine Query Language](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html)). In your example, assuming you have entity named Orders with Product property, just go ahead and do the following:

```
$dql_query = $em->createQuery("
    SELECT o FROM AcmeCodeBundle:Orders o
    WHERE 
      o.OrderEmail = 'some@mail.com' AND
      o.Product LIKE 'My Products%'
");
$orders = $dql_query->getResult();
```

Should do exactly what you need.

Comment: This code snippet creates the ability of SQL injection, if you like to build the query yourself, rather use the answer by @ManseUK.

But that's not what the OP wanted anyway..

Comment: @Dennis98 does every `->createQuery( )` create the ability of a SQL injection? Or is there something else wrong here?

Comment: @OmarTrkzi, there should have been **placeholders** instead of actual parameter values, which you then fill up using `AbstractQuery::setParameter()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also consider using DBAL:

```php
$qb = $em->getRepository("Orders")->createQueryBuilder('o');
$result = $qb->where('o.OrderEmail = :email')
   ->andWhere($qb->expr()->like('o.Product', ':product'))
   ->setParameter('email', 'some@mail.com')
   ->setParameter('product', 'My Products%')
   ->getQuery()
   ->getResult();
```

Answer (score 2):

The right answer to the question how to use LIKE in Doctrine would be using the Expression "Contains":

```
$expressionBuilder = Criteria::expr();

$expression = $expressionBuilder->contains('fieldName', 'value');

$collection->matching(new Criteria($expression));
```

Comment: Note: there is also `$expressionBuilder->startsWith()` and `$expressionBuilder->endsWith()`, to cover `'foo%'` and `'%foo'` cases.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you just need to tell doctrine who's your repository class, if you don't, doctrine uses default repo instead of yours.

```
@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Company\NameOfBundle\Repository\NameOfRepository")
```

Answer (score -4):

you can also do it like that :

```
$ver = $em->getRepository('GedDocumentBundle:version')->search($val);

$tail = sizeof($ver);
```

Comment: Please, don't use `sizeof`, it's a bad practice. 

And `EntityRepository->search()` is not existing, use `->find()` at least.