# How to use LIKE clause in DQL?

Tags: symfony, dql

I'm trying to create a query using the LIKE clause in Doctrine Query Language.

My query is as following:

```
public function findByName($keyword){
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $consulta = $em->createQuery('SELECT o FROM AppBundle:Items o WHERE o.name LIKE :keyword');
    $consulta->setParameter('keyword', '%'.$keyword.'%');
    return $consulta->getResult();
}
```

I'm getting the next errors:

```
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null
```

While if I do the same query but instead of LIKE i simply use =, the query executes correctly and I get the results. What could I be doing wrong here?

Thanks for the help.

Debug info:

> object(Doctrine\ORM\Query)#901 (24) {
> ["_state":"Doctrine\ORM\Query":private]=> int(2)
> ["_parsedTypes":"Doctrine\ORM\Query":private]=> array(0) { }
> ["_dql":"Doctrine\ORM\Query":private]=> string(57) "SELECT o FROM
> AppBundle:Coche o WHERE o.modelo = :keyword"
> ["_parserResult":"Doctrine\ORM\Query":private]=> NULL
> ["_firstResult":"Doctrine\ORM\Query":private]=> NULL
> ["_maxResults":"Doctrine\ORM\Query":private]=> NULL
> ["_queryCache":"Doctrine\ORM\Query":private]=> NULL
> ["_expireQueryCache":"Doctrine\ORM\Query":private]=> bool(false)
> ["_queryCacheTTL":"Doctrine\ORM\Query":private]=> NULL
> ["_useQueryCache":"Doctrine\ORM\Query":private]=> bool(true)
> ["parameters":protected]=>
> object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)#946 (1) {
> ["elements":"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection":private]=>
> array(1) { [0]=> object(Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parameter)#913 (3) {
> ["name":"Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parameter":private]=> string(7) "keyword"
> ["value":"Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parameter":private]=> int(1)
> ["type":"Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parameter":private]=> string(7) "integer"
> } } } ["_resultSetMapping":protected]=> NULL ["_em":protected]=>
> object(Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager)#740 (11) {
> ["config":"Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager":private]=>
> object(Doctrine\ORM\Configuration)#564 (1) {
> ["_attributes":protected]=> array(14) { ["entityNamespaces"]=>
> array(1) { ["AppBundle"]=> string(16) "AppBundle\Entity" }
> ["metadataCacheImpl"]=> object(Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache)#566
> (6) { ["data":"Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache":private]=> array(0) {
> } ["hitsCount":"Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache":private]=> int(0)
> ["missesCount":"Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache":private]=> int(0)
> ["upTime":"Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache":private]=>
> int(1598445780)
> ["namespace":"Doctrine\Common\Cache\CacheProvider":private]=>
> string(79)
> "sf_orm_default_061d80f6e71229c042b639f23634872f7045193d957ba060c640bf0458feeae2"
> ["namespaceVersion":"Doctrine\Common\Cache\CacheProvider":private]=>
> NULL } ["queryCacheImpl"]=>

```
    public function LikeExpression()
    {
        $stringExpr = $this->StringExpression();
        $not = false;
        if ($this->lexer->isNextToken(Lexer::T_NOT)) {
            $this->match(Lexer::T_NOT);
            $not = true;
        }
        $this->match(Lexer::T_LIKE);
        if ($this->lexer->isNextToken(Lexer::T_INPUT_PARAMETER)) {
            $this->match(Lexer::T_INPUT_PARAMETER);
            $stringPattern = new AST\InputParameter($this->lexer->token['value']);
        } else {
            $stringPattern = $this->StringPrimary();
        }
        $escapeChar = null;

//////// Highlighted error area//////////
        if ($this->lexer->lookahead['type'] === Lexer::T_ESCAPE) {
            $this->match(Lexer::T_ESCAPE);
            $this->match(Lexer::T_STRING);
            $escapeChar = new AST\Literal(AST\Literal::STRING, $this->lexer->token['value']);
        }
////////////////////////////////////////



        $likeExpr = new AST\LikeExpression($stringExpr, $stringPattern, $escapeChar);
        $likeExpr->not = $not;
        return $likeExpr;
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164682/doctrine-and-like-query

Comment: Hello I've tried that already, but it doesn't work, I have a repository for my entity where I have this find method. Do i have to create the query directly in the controller? I tried the query builder method in the repository and it didnt work for me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? What's the **exact** error message?

Comment: This error doesn't seams to be the result of an error in doctrine. Your query looks ok. The problem is not about dql. Can you provide more details ? Have you try to debug the query (use ``dump($var)``)...

Comment: The main error I'm getting is 'Trying to access array offset on value of type null' as i said in my question. Aside from that, I'm getting Parser->LikeExpression(), Parser->SimpleConditionalExpression() errors displayed on the symfony profiler.

Comment: Could we see the bit of code where you used the result of your findByName method ? The error is not a doctrine one

Comment: Sorry, If i var_dump the query, I get a page of almost thousand lines of info. I'm gonna update my initial post with the info i think you could maybe help me with. Thanks for  your patience and sorry for my ignorance (learning symfony)

Comment: @DylanKas, i simply pass my result to my twig template using the render method. I don't think there is something wrong with this, otherwise using name = 'term' wouldn't work either, right?

Comment: Please instead of doing that : ``return $consulta->getResult();`` Try doing this ``dump($consulta->getQuery()->getDQL()); die();``.
Please note that the ``dump()`` method require ``symfony/var-dumper`` component

Comment: dd($consulta->getQuery()->getDQL()); works as well

Comment: But i'm pretty sure that the problem is not about doctrine... Even though we haven't see any of your Entity. I suggest you to targeting the problem by debugging.

Comment: I get an error of non existent getQuery() method. With getDQL, i get the same DQL that i used when creating the query. I'm going to keep investigating what might cause the issue and post if I find an answer if it might help someone in the future. Thanks for your patience everyone!

Comment: I just thinking about it now, have you check what's inside ``$keyword`` ? You can also try ``getSQL()``. If it work, then your query is correct and the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: The $keyword is a simple string im introducing through a form, its the name of a car i have saved in my db. Btw, as a last hope, i updated my post with the next error area symfony profiler highlights me. It says something about character escaping, maybe something regarding that?

Comment: What you post is just highligting doctrine code. This cannot be the problem.
This can be a problem with an entity fields, or a problem with your query string. Have you try to do it this way : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8164858/6503197 ?

Comment: Yes, I understand that there isn't any problem with that code. What i understood was that Im getting this error because I have some problem related to character escaping or whatever that highlighted area means. I have my method exactly as the example you pointed out. Appreciate your help, gonna keep looking into it!

Comment: Hello, I just found out https://github.com/doctrine/orm/pull/7785/files# , changing one line of the doctrine code I was able to get the results with the like clause, I don't know why or how I had any errors in my doctrine code, but if it helps anyone, theres that. Thanks everyone else for the help! Added solution to op.

Comment: @xypher to answer your own question you should use the Answer section. Thanks!